# C# How to find a 1x1 image tag in HTML

Tags: c#, html, regex, tracking-pixel

I would like to know how to find an image tag in a string of HTML that has dimensions of 1x1, basically I am looking for tracking pixels. So for example:

```
<img src=\"http://somewhere.com\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\" style=\"display:none!important;\">
```

My end goal is to be able to find this part of the code and remove it from the string.

I have read few a few posts already on how to find all img tags but that is not what I am looking for. I only want the img tags that are 1x1.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Note that the width and height can also be set from CSS

Comment: Thanks Peter! I'll keep that in mind for the next iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove this `img` tags from your string, you can do that with regexp:

```
 string result = Regex.Replace(html, "<img.+?(width|height)=[\"']1[\"'].+?(width|height)=[\"']1[\"'].*>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: That is incorrect, because it will match width='1' or width="1", but not width=\"1\". And also it will match stuff like width="1'. `[\"']1[\"']` should be changed to `(\\"1\\"|'1')`

Comment: This worked nicely for my immediate needs! I will still look into HTML Agility Pack

Answer (score 3):

Not really a very good practice of parsing HTML with regexp, but I guess you colud get all `<img>` tags with `<img.*?>` and then do your regular

```
if (str.IndexOf("width=\"1\"" > 0 && str.IndexOf("height=\"1\"") > 0)
```

but there is much more to it, and I suggest you take a look at [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry! Agility Pack looks nice, I'll look into it :D